# Help me find an obscure series that I've received a long time ago in a form of a CD disk

Tags: story-identification

So, I'm about 5 years old (in 2005), and I get a strange-looking Video CD (I don't know how I got it). On it, there is a dim yellow picture of a woman (I think). Well, I decided to watch it and see what's all about. All I can remember is the following plot: the story begins with some boy whose mother died in a car accident (when the actual accident occurs, there is a black dog present in the scene, clearly hinting at something ominous). Well, the mother is dead, and that's all I can remember about her and the boy. The next scene is located in a castle, where a black-clothed queen is sitting on a big black throne. I don't remember any *events* that would solidify my presumptions, but I feel like she is portrayed as evil and somehow connected to the black dog and the boy's mother's death. And the CD ends right there, convincing me of the fact that what I've witnessed is a *series*, not a *film*.

The series itself had one special touch that I can remember: there were no vibrant colours in it, no, rather yellow-greyish filter all throughout. It also seemed that the main focus was on the tangled fates of both the boy and the black queen. It's really hard for me to tell, because I'm quite sure the CD **contained the first episode of the series!**

I don't remember the language of the series. It *could* be English but Polish or Czech are *also* plausible candidates. I saw it in Slovenia. **The series is live-action.**

This one is really obscure, and I'll be surprised if anyone figures it out. However, don't let yourself be discouraged. All suggestions and guesses are warmly welcome. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Thunderforge CD as in normal circular CD disk that you put into a device to watch something. So yes, a Video CD. I was in Slovenia when I discovered the series (Slovenia is my home country).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that it's a VCD. In countries such as the United States, they are virtually unheard of (VHS tapes were far more common).

Comment: Since you saw it in 2005, would you say it's possible that the yellow-gray color was caused by the show being pirated and burned to a disk?

Comment: Note that a single VCD not containing a complete story doesn't entirely rule out a film, as VCD is IIRC limited to about 70 minutes per disc, so a film would typically be split over two.

Comment: Another possibility might perhaps be a movie trailer?

Comment: @HarryJohnston No, it was definitely a ~40 minute long part of a series.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that this was an episode of *Tales from the Neverending Story* ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tales_from_the_Neverending_Story), [fandom.com](https://theneverendingstory.fandom.com/wiki/Tales_from_the_Neverending_Story))

The mother's death in the car accident occurs in Episode 1 - you can see the crash scene and the black dog at 1:17 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QqN6uv34qVI)

[image]

[image]

That said, the next scene does *not* have the queen sitting on a throne - although there is an evil queen, who you can see at 30:24 (she looks like she's wearing black) and 1:24:30 (black clothes, a chair of some sort, though I'm not sure I'd call it a throne.)

[image]

[image]

I checked Episodes 2 and 3 on Youtube, as it sounded like you may have seen a *"Previously..."* recap at the start of a later episode - but there was no recap, so I think you would have seen Episode 1.